# how to add timestamp in expect console log file

Tags: tcl, expect

I am sending some commands to a server which will run for more than 1 hour, I am using expect `log_file` feature to collect the console logs. My requirement is to add `timestamp` in the log file.

Is there any way to add every seconds `timestamp` in the log file which i got from `log_file` commands.

Answer (score 2):

`log_file` does not have in-built support for adding `timestamp` into the log file directly. So, we have to find another way to do. i.e. using some external file monitoring.

```
 tail -f dummy.log | while read line; do echo -n $(date +'%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S:%3N'); echo -e "\t$line"; done > session.log
```

Here `dummy.log` is the actual log file being created by `Expect` and `Session.log` is the new one created by us with timestamp added into it.

Comment: ...and if you're on a Debian system (or its derivative such as Ubuntu), you can just pipe the output of your Expect script to the `ts` program from the [`moreutils` package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/moreutils).

Comment: Thanks for the reply .I have doubt ..here how i will start both the process together ,I mean sending main command and tail . both will be sequential right or I should  start tail by some other background process.